# How to correct an error in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I've coded on SQL Server 2014:

```
create table CriticalStop
(
    SAP_ID int not null,
    Affected_ID char(15) not null,
    FnLoc_ID char(20) not null,
    MalFn_date date,
    MalFn_time time,
    MalFnHour_dur float,
    MalFnMajor char(15),

    primary key(SAP_ID)
);
go

insert into CriticalStop(SAP_ID, Affected_ID, FnLoc_ID, MalFn_date, MalFn_time, MalFnHour_dur, MalFnMajor)
values (10045929, 'TN.211-HC1', 'TN.211-HC1', convert(date,'20190101'), convert(time,'18:29:00.290'), 3.52, 'Process')
```

They was okay. but when I used statement below, SQL Server 2014 raised an error

```
select 
    SAP_ID,
    Affected_ID,
    FnLoc_ID,
    MalFn_date+3 as MalFn_delay,
    MalFn_time,
    MalFnHour_dur,
    MalFnMajor
from 
    CriticalStop;
```

Error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2314
>   Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int.

Line 2314 was pointing to SELECT statement above. I don't understand why this error happens on line `MalFn_date+3 as MalFn_delay`. I remove `+3`, the result is okay, but I need to change its date. How can I get it working with `+3`.

Comment: What does 3 represent? minutes? hours? days?

Comment: I thought that a date type was an integer. I was changing its day, by adding with an integer number.

Comment: Dates are sometimes stored as integers, but that's usually an offset in seconds or milliseconds since midnight, 1970, aka "the epoch". In databases, dates are their own type.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider storing your date and time as a single field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says what the problem is right in the error message, `date is incompatible with int`. You're trying to add an integer to a date field.

```
MalFn_date+3 as MalFn_delay,
```

You need to convert the integer to a time range so that it can be added to the date. SQL has no idea what `3` represents; seconds, minutes, days?

You can use the [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) function to do this in SQL Server. For example, if you wanted to add 3 days,

```
DATEADD(day, 3, MalFn_date)
```